# Arrange the code to separate functions in C

Tags: c, stack, parentheses, brackets

I make my exercise at the University and here it is: "Enter the equation, check if there is a bracket. If it is opening - push into a stack. If it is closing - check if the head element of the stack is opening brackets/parentheses. If the stack is empty, the equation is correct". I made the code to check it in the main() function. But it is needed to check if the element of the equation is a bracket/parentheses in the first function and comparing with the next bracket/parentheses.

Thanks a lot if you help me). CODE IS BELOW:

```
#include <stdio.h> <stdlib.h> <string.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 20
#define OVERFLOW -100
#define UNDERFLOW -101

///BEGIN DEFINING
typedef char C;
typedef struct Stack_tag {
    C data[STACK_SIZE];
    size_t size;
} Stack;
///END DEFINING

///BEGIN STACK FUNCTIONS
void Push(Stack* stack, const C value) {
    if (stack->size >= STACK_SIZE) exit(OVERFLOW);

    stack->data[stack->size] = value;
    stack->size++;
}

C Pop(Stack* stack) {
    if (stack->size == 0) exit(UNDERFLOW);

    stack->size--;
    return stack->data[stack->size];
}

C Peek(const Stack* stack) {
    if (stack->size <= 0) exit(UNDERFLOW);
    return stack->data[stack->size - 1];
}

void PrintStackValue(const C value) {
    printf("%c", value);
}

void PrintStack(const Stack* stack, void(*PrintStackValue)(const C)) {
    int i, len = stack->size - 1;
    printf("\nStack %d", stack->size);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        PrintStackValue(stack->data[i]);
        printf(" | ");
    }
    if (stack->size != 0) {
        PrintStackValue(stack->data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
///END STACK FUNCTIONS

///BEGIN OTHER FUNCTIONS
char isBr(char item) {
    switch (item) {
    case '(': return '(';
    case ')': return ')';
    case '[': return '[';
    case ']': return ']';
    case '{': return '{';
    case '}': return '}';
    default: return NULL;
    }
}
void Check(char item, Stack stack) {
    switch (item) {
    case '(': Push(&stack, item);
    case '[': Push(&stack, item);
    case '{': Push(&stack, item);
    case ')': if (Peek(&stack) == '(') Pop(&stack);
    case ']': if (Peek(&stack) == ']') Pop(&stack);
    case '}': if (Peek(&stack) == '}') Pop(&stack);
    }
}
///END OTHER FUNCTIONS
int main()
{
    Stack stack;
    stack.size = 0;
    ///EQUATION
    char* equation;
    int i;
    equation = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    printf("Enter the Equation: \n");
    gets(equation);
    ///CHECKING PROCESS
    ///TODO:
    ///1) SEPARATE FUNCTIONS
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(equation); i++) {
        /*
        if (equation[i] == '(' || equation[i] == '{' || equation[i] == '[') {
            Push(&stack, equation[i]);
        }
        if (equation[i] == ')') {
            if (Peek(&stack) == '(') Pop(&stack);
        }
        if (equation[i] == '}') {
            if (Peek(&stack) == '{') Pop(&stack);
        }
        if (equation[i] == ']') {
            if (Peek(&stack) == '[') Pop(&stack);
        }
        */
        char p = isBr(equation[i]);
        Check(p, stack);

    }



    ///PRINT THE RESULT
    puts(stack.size == 0 ? "FINE" : "NOOPE!!!");
    //PrintStack(&stack, PrintStackValue);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Tangent] Don't use `gets`.  It was deprecated and has since been removed from C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here:

- When you pass the stack structure to `Check`, the function sees a copy of the stack. Therefore, the changes you make are lost in `main` – they were only made to the copy. Pass a pointer to the structure, just as you have done for the functions for the stack operations. (Since the variable `stack` will then be a pointer in `Check`, you should pass `stack`, not `&stack` to the stack functions.)
- The cases in a `switch` statement in C are not isolated. The execution will "fall through" to the next case if you don't end the code with `break` or `return`.

Your check function could look like this:

```
void Check(char item, Stack *stack) {
    switch (item) {
    case '(': Push(stack, item); break;
    case '[': Push(stack, item); break;
    case '{': Push(stack, item); break;
    case ')': if (Peek(stack) == '(') Pop(stack); break;
    case ']': if (Peek(stack) == ']') Pop(stack); break;
    case '}': if (Peek(stack) == '}') Pop(stack); break;
    }
}
```

and you call it from main like this:

```
Check(p, &stack);
```

Further observations:

- A stack underflow should not cause an immediate exit of the program,. Instead, it should lead to a message that says that the equation is malformed.
- As noted in comments, don't use the unsafe and deprecated function `gets`. Use `fgets` instead.
- There's really no need to allocate a buffer of 100 chars on the heap with `malloc`. Just use an automatic array: `char equation[100];`. If you use `malloc`, you must also use `free` before you return from `main`.

Comment: If OP were to use `malloc()`, is there really a benefit to freeing that memory before the program exits?

Comment: Well, the system should clean up the resources of course, but in my opnion that is bad practice. I think learners should make a habit of `free`ing allocated memory, `fclose`ing open files and so on. in C, you must manage the resources yourself, so better get used to it.